# How to create a Multi-Network subsite?

Tags: wordpress

I've enabled Wordpress Multisite (subdomains) on `www.example.com` and created a subsite @ `s.example.com`, and then installed/enabled [WP Multi-Network](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/).

I've created a new network @ `s.example.com`.

How do I create a subsite in that network, e.g. `s.example.com/subsite`?

`s.example.com/wp-admin/network` redirects to `www.example.com/wp-admin/network`.

If I create a new site @ `www.example.com/wp-admin/network/sites.php`, I can't make it a subdomain or subdirectory of `s.example.com`.

Help appreciated.

Comment: could you please explain how the virtual hosts are configurated? Have you create the right configuration in your server for s.example.com that has document_root with the path to the multisite subsite? Or if you are in a shared hosting, have you set the subdomain to the right path?

Comment: Yes @AntoninoScarfì, I have a wildcard subdomain pointing to the web root of the domain. `s.example.com` loads fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is just like @Ravi says, you can't create a multisite within a multisite environment. s.example.com is a multisite website, you can't split that multisite site into multiple other sites. Need to have 2 separate installs.

Comment: That's not correct. *You can* create a multisite within a multisite environment using the [WP Multi-Network](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can go to the dashboard of S.yoursite.com and creat a page subsite and assign a separate temple with different look.

Answer (score -1):

(If anyone here would like to correct me please do)

It kind of sounds like you want to make a multisite inside a multisite. Multisite was probably not made to work like this.

When you make a WordPress Multisite you are asked to configure it using either subdomains or subfolder structure. You will be able to switch but you won't be able to mix this up.

A possible solution would be to make a subdomain in your hosting package (s.example.com) and configure a separate multisite (with subfolder structure) for this. The drawback will be that you will have 2 seperate networks instead of 1 network.

Like this you can have: s.example.com/site-1, s.example.com/site-2, www.example.com/site-1, and www.example.com/site-2

Comment: Hi Ravi, a multisite inside a multisite is just what WP Multi-Network creates.